# How to view /template data from existing db using model in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I managed to connect existing mySQL with Django , but when I tried to view in my app. using :

```
from task.models import stats

data = stats.objects.all()
for e in data:
  print e.name, 'starts on', e.start_date
```

It kept tell me that stats is not exist. I used settings.py to link the existing db and I was able to verify it. But I'm not sure how to get data from the model to views in my template. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far. I got model with "billing" and "stats" table , If I inspect model I got `>> python manage.py inspectdb`

[image]

================edit==================

Adding to above, I'm new to Django so is it possible that I got mess up with how I set up the app , would that related ?

under **settings.py** I got install app below : I tried put in billing / stats but it didn't work. what am I missing here.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
    'task',
    # 'Billing',
    # 'Stats',
)
```

[image]

Here's my folder

Comment: It is case sensitive. did you try `Stats` instead?

Comment: Yes , "cannot import name Stats"  that's what I got

Comment: Did you actually add the result of `inspectdb` to tasks/models.py?

Comment: oh.. that's probably it , i'll tried. I followed the instruction, but didn't see that part. hmm